Unnecessary assumptions in Proposition 3.28 of Bridson and Haefliger's book Metric Spaces of Non-positive Curvature
In Bridson and Haefliger's book Metric Spaces of Non-positive Curvature we are given the following proposition (Proposition 3.28)
Let $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ be a map of length spaces such that
(1) $X$ is connected,
(2) $p$ is a local homeomorphism,
(3) the length of every path in $\tilde{X}$ is not bigger than the
length of its image under $p$,
(4) $X$ is locally uniquely geodesic and geodesics in $X$ vary
continuously with their endpoints locally, and
(5) $\tilde{X}$ is complete.
Then $p$ is a covering map.
and its consequent proof (as the proof is long, I did not add it). I have gone through the proof and I am unable to find any step that uses the assumption that $X$ and $\tilde{X}$ are length spaces.
What furthers my suspicion that the length space assumption is unnecessary is that later in the book in Corollary 4.7 the spaces involved are not length spaces, yet in the proof of the Corollary they use the above proposition.
Can anyone explain what I am missing?

Your question should be self-contained and currently it is not. What is the statement of the proposition?

@MoisheKohan Sorry, this is my first posted question and I had trouble with uploading the image, should be fine now.

Parts 3 and 4 make no sense if you do not assume that you have length spaces.

@MoisheKohan The definition of a length space given in this book is that the distance between any two points is equal to the infimum of lengths of rectifiable paths between them. You can define lengths of curves in an arbitrary metric spaces, so I do not understand your comment.

Yes, but imagine a space which contains no nonconstant rectifiable curves.

@MoisheKohan The assumptions that $X$ is connected and locally geodesic are actually already sufficient to show that there exist rectifiable paths between any two points. Please recall my original question.
